# Group blocks of rows to apply different subtractions (not a function) per block in data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am a novice to R but I was wondering if there is a way to apply a specific calculation (not a function) to separate blocks of rows in a data frame. In my example I have the following data frame called races (below) and I want to add a variable called diff_towinner where I take the speed of a racer and subtract it from the winner speed. In my simple code (below) I was able to add a column, but the calculation of the speed difference doesn't break down into races (blocks of rows), instead, for race B and C, it considers the winner speed of race A for all rows.

```
race position speed 
A      1        340     
A      2        320   
A      3        316   
B      1        350   
B      2        345   
B      3        332   
C      1        325   
C      2        320  
C      3        311
```

My simple code:

```
top_speed <- races %>% 
  group_by(race) %>% 
  summarise(winner_speed = max(speed))

race <- merge(race, top_speed, by="race")

for (i in 1:nrow(races)){
    races$diff_towinner[[i]] = races$winner_speed[[i]] - races$speed[[i]]
  }
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the extra step, you could use mutate to create the extra column at once:

```
library(dplyr)

races = read.table(text="race position speed 
A 1 340 
A 2 320 
A 3 316 
B 1 350 
B 2 345 
B 3 332 
C 1 325 
C 2 320 
C 3 311",header=T)


top_speed <- races %>% 
group_by(race) %>% 
  mutate(diff_to_winner = max(speed)-speed) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Output:

```
  race position speed diff_to_winner
1    A        1   340              0
2    A        2   320             20
3    A        3   316             24
4    B        1   350              0
5    B        2   345              5
6    B        3   332             18
7    C        1   325              0
8    C        2   320              5
9    C        3   311             14
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Florian, thank you!!!! I knew it was something simple. I am on my week 4 of R programming. I will get there. :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Good attempt for just 4 weeks of R programming, you'll definitely get there!